# What is == $0 in developer tool after the end of every line of code?

Tags: browser, web, developer-tools, web-developer-toolbar

[image]

I want to know what is the `== $0` in developer tool, it is marked by red in the screenshot.
I found this `== $0` in code of every website in developer tool and want to know what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 refers to the current selected element in your source.

It means that you can access to this element in the DevTools console by simply typing:

```
$0
```

From there, you can do whatever you like with this element, by using [Javascript DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

See [Chrome DevTools reference](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4)

Answer (score 1):

I personally am not seeing this, but $0 usually refers to the element currently inspected.

Try it out by right-clicking this comment and choose "Inspect element" in Google Chrome. If you pop over to the console and type out $0, it will select the element in the page and print it out in the console.