# How to use CSS locator to identify close control in a dialog

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have locator of one close control on a dialog as below

```
span.close-modal.close::after
```

Please let me know how I should pick `CSS#` for this locator

Comment: Could you share HTML as well?? do want to know how to get element by this cssSelector `span.close-modal.close::after`??

Comment: `<div class="modal-content full-width"><span class="close-modal close">
::after==$0
</span>`

Comment: So here do you want to locate `span` element??

Comment: when I inspect the close control, I see that ::after==$ 0 is getting highlighted in the DOM. but not sure how to capture it as locator.

Comment: Try to locate `span` element and click on it. May be it works..

Answer (score 0):

About ==$0, see that: [What is == $0 in developer tool after the end of every line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115354/what-is-0-in-developer-tool-after-the-end-of-every-line-of-code)

`$0` can't be select with selectors. It doesn't exist in html code.